# when enter number then letter it's read like number

Tags: php

it's simple code

```
$value=($_POST['value']>0)?"number":"string";
echo $value;
```

when i insert some thing like 123abc this code print number but if i insert something like abc123 it this code print string

now i use alot of if syntax and every time when insert 123abc it always print number
and if i use it like this

```
$value=$_POST['value']*1;
echo $value;
```

when i insert some thing like 123abc this code print 123 but if i insert something like abc123 it this code print 0

now the main question is why the code work ilke this 

and is there simple way to treat this and sure it's number before i insert it at database or whatever

Comment: Because that's... oh wait, I already made that joke.

Comment: This is more or less undefined behaviour and you shouldn't count on it. Instead, use `is_numeric()`.

Comment: @kba: It is perfectly defined. Insane, but defined.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Where are the rules defined for this?

Comment: @kba: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: @kba more specifically, here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion "_If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0_"

Comment: so it's normal that the code run like that

Comment: @robert: It's normal for PHP.

Comment: @robert Even if it's _normal_, I wouldn't recommend writing an application that depends on this obscure logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this for checking if `$_POST['value']` is string or number and if it is more than 0.

```
$value=is_numeric($_POST['value']) && ($_POST['value']>0) ? "number":"string";
```

If `$_POST['value']` is `abc123` or `123abc` it will print "string" and if it's just `123`, it will print "number".

[Demo](https://eval.in/102098)

PHP on [their documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) states that :

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.